# Override Download Header CURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to get image from url.
when i execute url https://www.bing.com/hpwp/5c1d8376b1924366050f7acc7c653dad

its return download file.

what i ask is can i display image from that url without downloading it?

i also try with this CURL

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url_bing_image_hd);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Google Chrome');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-type: image/jpeg', 'Content-Disposition: inline']);

$response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$err = curl_error($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

but it doesn't work.
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Do you want to simply display the image from the URL? Then there is no need to use curl, simply do 

echo '<img src="'.$url_bing_image_hd.'"/>';

Comment: no, i want to save the image @maio290